How to implement "wait_sec_between_publish: " in milliseconds?
Hi I am currently trying to set positions for my motor drivers wiht ROS2, am not entirely an expert but figure I can ask here.
My question is in most config yaml file especially when it comes to forward publisher config yaml files, I often see in the examplese wait_sec_between_publish: X.
I tried testing them, and it turns out they only work with integers,  therefore implementing them in milliseconds prove to be a challenge for me, does anyone here know any solution to this? I tried looking through the repos, but can't seem to find any solution.
Would appreciate the help!

To understand your question, are you using ros2_control (you tagged it) or a simple ROS 2 node?
